# Cannot override `toString` when extending `Error` w/webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm trying to build a custom exception that inherits from `Error` but webpack doesn't seem to like it.  The code works fine directly in the node REPL as well as chrome's console [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP3z4.png)], but neither in node or the browser when compiled by webpack (version: webpack@~2.1.0-beta.17).

uncompiled code:

```
export default class Exception extends Error {
  constructor(message, inner) {
    super(message);

    this.name = 'Exception';
    this.message = message; 
    this.inner = inner;
    if (typeof super.constructor.captureStackTrace === 'function') {
      super.constructor.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    } else {
      const stack = (new super.constructor(message)).stack;
      this.stack = stack.split('\n').slice(1).map(l => l.trim()).join('\n');
    }
  }

  toString() {
    let string = this.stack;

    if (this.inner) {
      const innerLines = this.inner.toString().split('\n');
      const inner = innerLines.map(line => {
        return line.replace(/^(\s+)/g, function($0, $1) {
          return `  ${$1}`;
        });
      }).join('\n');
      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
      string = (string + '\n' +
        '  Inner ' + inner);
    }

    return string;
  }
}
```

relevant test:

```
describe('Exception', () => {

  describe('toString', () => {
    it('should return the `name`: `message` + `stack` (recursively if there are inner exceptions)', () => {
      const innerMessage = 'foo bar!';
      const outerMessage = 'bar foo!';
      const inner = new Exception(innerMessage);
      const outer = new Exception(outerMessage, inner);

      expect(inner.toString())
        .to.match(new RegExp(`Exception: ${innerMessage}`));
      expect(outer.toString())
        .to.match(new RegExp(`Exception: ${outerMessage}`))
        .and.to.match(new RegExp(`Inner Exception: ${innerMessage}`));
    });
  });
});
```

failure:

```
1) Exception toString should return the `name`: `message` + `stack` (recursively if there are inner exceptions):
     AssertionError: expected 'Exception: bar foo!' to match /Inner Exception: foo bar!/
      at Context.<anonymous> (.test/test/unit/shared/lib/exceptions/exception.compiledtest:178:90)
```

compiled: https://gist.github.com/dwick/4d29c679f5a1c8260f22d619c3167524

Everything works as expected if I don't inherit from `Error`, however I'd really like `e instanceof Error` to work.

It's pretty clear what's going on when logging `toString` an instance of `Exception` vs the constructor itself:

```
> console.log('instance:', outer.toString.toString());
instance: function toString() { [native code] }
> console.log('prototype:', Exception.prototype.toString.toString());
prototype: function toString() {
      var string = this.stack;

      if (this.inner) {
        var innerLines = this.inner.toString().split('\n');
        var inner = innerLines.map(function (line) {
          return line.replace(/^(\s+)/g, function ($0, $1) {
            return '  ' + $1;
          });
        }).join('\n');
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
        string = string + '\n' + '  Inner ' + inner;
      }

      return string;
    }
```

Just confused as to why and how to fix this.  FWIW I've also tried and got the same result:

```
class Exception extends Error { ... }
Exception.prototype.toString = ...
```

Comment: thinking it might actually be babel's fault: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes.  checking out to see if this fixes it: https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

Comment: You can reimplement with classic prototypal inheritance: https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#classes

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be babel.  From https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes:

> Built-in classes such as Date, Array, DOM etc cannot be properly subclassed due to limitations in ES5 (for the es2015-classes plugin). You can try to use babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend based on Object.setPrototypeOf and Reflect.construct, but it also has some limitations.

Comment: while this fixes errors from being thrown `instanceof` still doesn't work as expected.